# bootstrap grid - form-control takes full width of parent div, how to insert something next to it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the grid system of bootstrap.

My HTML looks as follows (jade syntax)

```
    form.form-horizontal(role='form', name='containerForm', id='containerForm', novalidate)
       fieldset 
          .form-group
              label.col-lg-2.control-label(for='ContType')
              .col-lg-4
                select.form-control(ng-model="data.ContainerType", id='ContType', name='ContType', ng-options='translate(s.name) for s in containerTypeList')
          .form-group

          (and so on)
```

The 'form-control' CSS class is taking 100% width of parent DIV (e.g. col-lg-4, these col-lg classes are effectively "table cells"):

```
 .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I need however to display some HTML right before the SELECT above (or, alternatively, after). I need that HTML to be in the same line as the SELECT. If I simply enter something after the SELECT now, it goes to next line, due to width=100% of that SELECT.

How I can possibly achieve my goal while keeping bootstrap classes in place?

Answer (score 2):

You could place both in a row, then put each item in it's own column. For example:

```
<div class="row col-sm-12">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Demo</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use an input-group, for example:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Demo</button>
    </span>
</div>
```